# Какая таблица БД отвечает за публикации, страницы и рубрики?

Tags: wordpress

В какой таблице БД находятся публикации, страницы и рубрики ?

Благодарю

Comment: А поиск видимо вашей религией запрещен https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Answer (score 1):

Посты и страницы находятся в таблице wp_posts а их доп. поля в wp_postmeta. Рубрики находятся в таблицах wp_terms

Comment: А их доп поля и связи - в `wp_termmeta`, `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_term_relationship`. Понятно, к чему автор клонит, и я не стал отвечать. Совет начинающим всегда один - не лезьте руками в базу, вам нечего там делать, вы всё сломаете. Используйте функции WordPress для работы с постами и таксономиями.

Comment: @KAGGDesign типичная проблема XY, но раз на неё можно ответить не задумываясь о причинах - отвечают. "#[нерусский форум](https://searchengines.guru/showpost.php?p=15431645&postcount=10)"